# mysql adding data with special autoincrement

Tags: sql-insert, mysql-5.7

I have a question about how to add data in the table users_in_queue? I want to add data from another table but field `number_in_queue` must be like an autoincrement column for each `queue_id`. I mean that data in the table must have this structure:

---

### user_id | queue_id | number_in_queue

### 1       |  1       |  1

### 2       |  1       |  2

### 3       |  2       |  1

### 4       |  1       |  3

[image: DB architecture]

Comment: which mysql version?

Comment: You need to give an example of how you are adding the data to this table.

Comment: mysql 5.7 insert using insert into @nbk

Comment: Ok, then you need user defined variables. you fill both tbales an also enter  a row in the relationship table and now yyou wnat to update that relationship table?

Comment: @nbk that table like connection table that contains rows from both tables and some addition fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The older version have to use some user variables  to get to your result.

That is why it is quite ugly

> ```
> CREATE Table user_in_queues(user_id INTEGER, queue_id INTEGER , number_in_queue  INTEGER)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user_in_queues VALUES (1,1,0),(2,1,0),(3,2,0),(4,1,0),(5,2,0);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_in_queues;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | queue_id | number_in_queue
> ------: | -------: | --------------:
>       1 |        1 |               0
>       2 |        1 |               0
>       3 |        2 |               0
>       4 |        1 |               0
>       5 |        2 |               0
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     user_id, queue_id, number_in_queue
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         user_id,
>             IF(@queue = queue_id, @rn:=@rn + 1, @rn:=1) number_in_queue,
>             @queue:=queue_id queue_id
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         *
>     FROM
>         user_in_queues
>     ORDER BY queue_id , user_id) t1, (SELECT @queue:=0) t2, (SELECT @rn:=0) t3) t4
> ORDER BY user_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | queue_id | number_in_queue
> ------: | -------: | --------------:
>       1 |        1 |               1
>       2 |        1 |               2
>       3 |        2 |               1
>       4 |        1 |               3
>       5 |        2 |               2
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE user_in_queues u
> SET number_in_queue = (SELECT 
>     number_in_queue
> FROM
>     (SELECT 
>         user_id,
>             IF(@queue = queue_id, @rn:=@rn + 1, @rn:=1) number_in_queue,
>             @queue:=queue_id queue_id
>     FROM
>         (SELECT 
>         *
>     FROM
>         user_in_queues
>     ORDER BY queue_id , user_id) t1, (SELECT @queue:=0) t2, (SELECT @rn:=0) t3) t4
>     WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND queue_id = u.queue_id )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_in_queues;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | queue_id | number_in_queue
> ------: | -------: | --------------:
>       1 |        1 |               1
>       2 |        1 |               2
>       3 |        2 |               1
>       4 |        1 |               3
>       5 |        2 |               2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4af85d5239e9a4c9d82f5bdbfccb98e0)*